# Appending a result from ajax into a textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, append, textarea

How can I append a result from ajax to a textarea? I am using codeigniter. I want to append the values that I've got in my controller to textarea.

Here is the result of my query that was passed in my controller, to be appended in my textarea:

```
checkup_diagnosis: [2]
  0: Object
     diagnosis: "Java"
  1: Object
     diagnosis: "Scala"
```

Now I want the two values to be inserted in my textarea. Here is what I've tried, where `#modaldiagnosis` is the ID of my textarea:

```
function view_profile(check_up_date,check_up_id) {
 $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"search_records/view_profbtn",
    type: "POST",
    data: {check_up_id:check_up_id, check_up_date:check_up_date},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
             $('#modaldiagnosis').append(data['checkup_diagnosis'][i]['diagnosis']);  
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `.val()` to set the content of a textarea element. To append to the existing value you can do this:

```
var md = $("#modaldiagnosis")
md.val(md.val() + valueToAppendHere)
```

However, repeatedly updating the same DOM element within a loop isn't a good idea. Better to use the loop to create a string to append and then update the DOM element once, *after* the loop.

Also, you may want to put a newline or comma or something between each value. Here's one way to do that:

```js
var data = {
  checkup_diagnosis: [
    { diagnosis: "Java" },
    { diagnosis: "Scala" }
  ]
}

$("button").click(function() {     // button with click handler for demo purposes only

  var newData = data['checkup_diagnosis']        // take the input array,
    .map(function(v) { return v['diagnosis'] })  // map it to get the required values,
    .join(", ")                                  // join the result with commas
  var md = $('#modaldiagnosis')
  md.val(md.val() + newData)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="modaldiagnosis"></textarea>
<button>Test</button>
```

Obviously you would have some Ajax code at the point where I've used a button click in my demo. You can see in the demo that the data gets added to the end of whatever is already in the textarea - testing if there is already a value and adding an extra comma (or whatever other formatting you want) is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: wow. great answer. i will update my question. please bare with my situation thank you ..

Comment: Regarding your update, just take the contents of the click handler that I had in my demo and put it in your Ajax success handler and it should work fine.

Comment: do i need this ? var newData = data['checkup_diagnosis']        // take the input array,
    .map(function(v) { return v['diagnosis'] })  // map it to get the required values,
    .join(", ")  my data is in ajax data

Comment: sorry sir i'm still a beginner in php

Comment: Yes. Take the five lines of code that I've shown inside the click handler, starting with `var newData =...` and ending with `md.val(md.val() + newData)`, and put them into your `success` function (after deleting your existing for loop).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will require

```
for(i=0; i<data['checkup_diagnosis'].length; i++) {
    $('#modaldiagnosis').append(data['checkup_diagnosis'][i]['diagnosis']);  
}
```

Comment: for(i=0; i<data['checkup_diagnosis'].length; i++)  {
          alert(i);
        }
why i cant alert the value of i ?

Comment: nnnnnn answer is much better, follow that instead :)